# C# - Several Threads Stuck Waiting for LowLevelLifoSemaphore.WaitNative

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, threadpool

I have a old DotNet 6 application running on linux that does a ton of synchronous DB calls and I am trying to debug a threading issue and I noticed that a lot of threads have the following callstack:

```
System.Private.CoreLib!System.Threading.LowLevelLifoSemaphore.WaitNative(class Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle,int32)
  System.Private.CoreLib!System.Threading.LowLevelLifoSemaphore.WaitForSignal(int32)
  System.Private.CoreLib!System.Threading.LowLevelLifoSemaphore.Wait(int32,bool)
  System.Private.CoreLib!System.Threading.PortableThreadPool+WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
```

That's the whole callstack, and there are many threads with this exact same stack.  What is this `LowLevelLifoSemaphore.WaitNative` about?  Is there some kind of low level deadlock going on?

Comment: You're asking people to guess what your application does. If you have a ton of synchronous DB calls though, you should expect to have a lot of waits. That's the very definition of `synchronous` - blocking until something completes

Comment: What threading issue are you trying to solve? Threads don't affect database concurrency or deadlocks anyway. Deadlocks occur when two connections wait to use objects (tables, rows) locked by each other. Just two connections that execute eg a `SELECT` and `UPDATE` in the wrong order are enough to cause a deadlock.

Comment: Sorry - thats the whole call stack - there is nothing else... so I'm trying to understand what threads with that callstack are doing.

Comment: _"there is nothing else... "_ - I would suppose there is some code also.

Comment: "PortableThreadPool" is a good hint.  You are looking at threadpool threads, waiting for work to do.  It is the normal state for a tp-thread.  You don't have a problem.

Comment: @Zeus82 just because there are some idle threadpool threads doesn't mean you have a threading problem. You can use a profiler, dotnet counters or ThreadPool methods like [ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.getavailablethreads?view=net-7.0) to see how many threads are in the threadpool. What's the *actual* problem though and why do you think it has something to do with threading?

Comment: .NET always published runtime metrics like thread counts, threadpool sizes, GCs, object allocations etc, all the way back to 2000. On Windows those are available through the OS's performance counters. On Linux there's no standard so things are a bit trickier. You can use tools like [dotnet-counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-counters) and [dotnet-monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-monitor) either on the same box [or a sidecar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/diagnostics-in-containers)

Comment: Most BCL libraries already publish metrics, you just need to read them. You can also create [your own custom metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/metrics-instrumentation) with a few lines of code. With a few extra lines all the metrics can be published as [Prometheus or OpenTelemetry metrics too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/metrics-collection). You can run `dotnet monitor` or create a Grafana dashboard to see what your application really does

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I'm just wondering what threads with this call stack are doing - are they just idle threads?

Comment: Yes. Threads [don't have an Idle state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.threadstate?view=net-7.0). They can either be running or waiting to run.

Comment: Use `dotnet monitor` or `dotnet counters` to see what's actually going on with the application. A large or increasing number of idle threads may mean there are threading issues, just not with the threadpool. They mean that there were so many blocked operations that the runtime had to increase the threadpool to handle a new request.

Comment: Those blocking operations may be caused by database blocking though, which can't be solved from the client. Perhaps there are missing indexes, or too many slow queries. The application wastes time waiting for those queries to finish. Using asynchronous operations will reduce the size of the threadpool but *won't* fix blocking. One option is to fix the queries so they run faster or read less. Another is to *limit* the number of concurrent queries so they don't block each other so much. A 3-way block is far easier to resolve than a 10-way block

Comment: One of the most effective ways to reduce blocking is to *not* keep connections open for long. ADO.NET DataTables and EF Core DbContexts were built to load any data they need as quickly as possible and then close the connection. When processing is done, any changes are saved in a new connections. No connection means no locks so no blocking